# Requesting extra permissions through Google sign in on Concrete5

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

We are currently trying to use Concrete5 to create an internal Intranet for the company I work for (this is a web-based server). What we would like to do is allow our employees to sign in using their Gmail and be able to see their personal calendars amongst other things on sign in.

I would like the employees to just sign in once, get automatically asked for granting permissions during the login, and then be taken to the home page.

**I'm having trouble figure out how to modify Concrete5's built-in Google login to request these scopes.** I am pretty bare-bones in my PHP knowledge and no amount of Google searching has really answered my question specifically for modifying the authentication for Concrete5.

So to sum up my question:

**How would someone go about modifying Concrete5's Google authentication to request additional permissions?** We are using 5.8.3 and are always updating as necessary, so modifying the core is not really an option to prevent overwrites in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that would be to copy the core Google login system to create a new one. You could call it Google Custom or anything you want. You could include it in the folder application/authentication or in a package, with the appropriate modifications.

But to be honest, if you're bare-bones in your PHP knowledge, it all might be a bit too difficult to achieve